# htaccess: how to avoid repeated conditions/rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Well known issue: Google indexing engine states it can see 2x2x2=8 duplicates of the URLs, where differences are

- http - https
- www - no www
- root/ - root/index.php

(8 duplicates for the root URL, and 4 duplicates for every other page URL)

I use the following **working code** in the .htaccess to obtain **301-redirect** for **all** of the duplicates:

```
RewriteEngine On

# first, www and root together
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/index.php [R=301,L]

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# add index.php to the root url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [R=301,L]

# finally, force https if none of the earlier conditions are met
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above code works well removing all duplicates with 301 redirect code. However, I believe it can be written a more elegant way, possibly **without doubling rewrite condidtions/rules**.

BTW I found hundreds(!) of posts giving advice and examples of the related .htaccess statements, and all of them are either incomplete or wrong! They usually stop after one condidtion is met, or don't result in 301 code in every cases.

Comment: It would certainly be shorter already, if you handled point 3) the other way around. (Who would _want_ the "ugly" version that shows index.php, to begin with?) And if you don't need it to be so "dynamic", but can directly write the _actual_ target host name instead of using `%{HTTP_HOST}` or extracts thereof, in those places, it can also be condensed down a bit more.

Comment: And multiple RewriteCond are joined with an implicit AND by default - but you can change that, by using the `[OR]` flag.

Comment: CBroe - thanks for the notes. I decided to show index.php because then I know how to make this URL canonical: I can add <link rel="canonical" ... etc. in the <head> of the file. But if I decide opposite the htaccess rules doubling remains.

Comment: If you are using `<link rel="canonical"` already, _and_ are actually setting that to the _correct_ "version" of the URL, then Google should not complain much anymore to begin with. Canonical links were _created_ for exactly that purpose, to tell search engines & co. what the real URL for a page is supposed to be. Not sure what exactly would be stopping you from setting the canonical URL _without_ the `index.php` part though.

Comment: I thought canonical should link to an actual file URL (and not to a domain URL)...  Anyway, I added for the need of Google: 1. sitemap.xml 2. canonical link in every file to be searched. After a week or more I have still a dozen of complains about duplicates. Should I be just more patient?...

Comment: Canonical should point to whatever you _specify_ as the "real" URL for a piece of content. "Files" have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (Google documents are not always easy to understand for me...).   But I'm still interested in how to code my original rules in a better way. I was doing experiments with [OR] [N] [S] [C] flags but cannot find satisfying solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly (already discussed in comments), your canonical "root" URL should simply be `/`, not `/index.php`. Users should not see `index.php` in the URL and if the canonical is `/index.php` then you are going to have to always redirect users (and search engines) that type/request the root domain and share URLs including the extra `index.php` - not good for anyone. Your [*canonical* link element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) for the root is then simply:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
```

And all internal links/anchors should state `href="/"`, not `href="/index.php"`.

Otherwise, the only "minor" issue I see in the rules you've posted is treating the root differently in the www to non-www redirect and having a separate rule for this. Although having separate rules is generally fine, providing the number of redirects is kept minimal, which they appear to be here.

Providing you are not implementing HSTS (in which case you would need to redirect to HTTPS first - on the same host - before other canonicalisation redirects) then you could combine these rules into one and minimise the number of redirects. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP and/or WWW and remove "index.php" (if any)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:(^|/)index\.php)?$ https://%1/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

I've kept the rules "generic" by not explicitly stating the domain name (but this then requires the 4th *condition* to get the hostname less the www subdomain). The rules could be "simplified" and would arguably be "more reliable" if the canonical hostname was hardcoded (depending on the server/environment).

The regex `^(.*?)(?:(^|/)index\.php)?$` matches any URL, but excludes the optional `index.php` (or `/index.php`) on the end of the URL in the first capturing subpattern (`$1`). Note that this regex does not only handle `/index.php` in the root, but also subdirectories, eg. `/foo/bar/index.php` (which ultimately redirects to `/foo/bar/`). The `$2` backreference simply contains the trailing slash when removing `index.php` from a subdirectory, otherwise it is *empty*.

Comment: Great answer, using the last regex is really smart for me! :-bd  As your index stripping works also for subdirectories, I replace `index\.php` with `index\.(php|html)` to reach both this cases.  HSTS: how to know if it is the case?  Side etiquette question: how should I reference to the advice if I'm going to share the solution outside stackoverflow?

Comment: @mja [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (and [HSTS Preload](https://hstspreload.org/)) is a decision you make as a site owner in order to further secure the site. See also my answer on Webmasters regarding the implementation of HSTS (with www): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/131970/1243 - You can share this solution using the [Share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77923996/369434) link below the answer to link back to my answer. Thanks.